# Mask URL with Selectors Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, aem, sling

I received a request asking to mask an url like this

commercial.com/en/test/page1 to commercial.com/en/test.page1  (as using selectos)

I tried with the next: 
**RewriteRule "^/en/test.page1" "https://${CommercialName}/en/test/page1" [L,P]**

In that case this does not work by sendming me the next server message:

**Bad Request**

*Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.*

But if I change my rule to this works: 
**RewriteRule "^/en/test.pagetest" "https://${CommercialName}/en/test/page1" [L,P]**

But then I add another rule and it shows me the same

**RewriteRule "^/en/test.pagetest" "https://${CommercialName}/en/test/page1" [L,P]**
**RewriteRule "^/en/test.page2test" "https://${CommercialName}/en/test/page2" [L,P]**

Do anyone knows why this error is caused?

PS:

- 1  I already tried to chage P into PT

  2. Apache 2.4
  3. Working with AEM as CMS
  4. I already tried using RewriteCond as  RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^/en/test.page2test"

Comment: Do you want to hide selectors, i.e. change request that comes as `/en/test/page1` to `/en/test.page1`? In this case you need to reverse rewrite rules as they change request's body, not the other way around I am afraid.